# Combine small messages in kafka topic to large file one

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka topic with a lot of messages.

1. **First step**, I want to combine them to size rotated files (10MB) or if there are no messages, time based rotated files (Max 1 hour)
2. **Second step**, After each combine, I want to add a message to other Kafka topic with the URL of the file.

I know that I can combine through kafka-connector, but I can't combine size based, only time based. 
Another problem with kafka-connector is that I didn't find any way to satisfy the "**Second step**"

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

There is no purpose in combining messages.

Kafka messages have a default max message size of 1MB.

Kafka is not mean for file transfers. If you must to that, use URI's like you say, or add Apache NiFi to your processing.

Unclear what Kafka Connector you are referring to

Comment: I need to transfer those messages, and transfer a lot of small messages would take an eternity. Thus, I want to combine to one big file and transfer. Did you understand to the motivation of combining those small messages to large file?
I want to export the Kafka messages to file system with combining

Comment: Kafka cannot handle one large file. There is no point of exporting data in Kafka topics to files on disk, either. Kafka is distributed. As soon as you write to disk, then you have lost the factor of durability... Sounds like what you want is just a multipart upload request to S3

Comment: The Kafka will handle only link to the file, the file will be saved on file system shared directory.

Comment: Okay, great. But still. Why cant you just upload that file directly where it will go?